# Logged user can't change password

Tags: windows, windows-10, administrator

I have stand alone Windows 10 PC not connected to any domain. I'm using PIN in order to login to system. Since I forgot my password I decided to change it. Got error below during pass change procedure:

```
---------------------------
Local Users and Groups
---------------------------
The following error occurred while attempting to set the password for user myName:

The system is not authoritative for the specified account and therefore cannot complete the operation. Please retry the operation using the provider associated with this account. If this is an online provider please use the provider's online site.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

User myName is in Administrators group. Why I can't change password? How to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you using a Microsoft account to sign in?

Comment: I don't remember I did so on this pc, but it is possible.

Comment: This is likely caused by using a Microsoft account. Changing your password will have to be done online.

Comment: @vico You need to determine if that’s the case or not.

Comment: Yes, it is MS account

Answer (score 2):

### Forgot Windows 10 password, how to change it with Microsoft account

> ### [How to reset your Microsoft account password](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026971/microsoft-account-how-to-reset-your-password)
>
> **Windows 10 PC**
>
> 1. On the sign-in screen, type your Microsoft account name if it's not
>      displayed.If there are multiple accounts on the PC, choose the one to reset.
> 2. Select **I forgot my password** below the password text box.
> 3. On the Recover your account screen, type the characters displayed in
>      the box below **Enter the characters you see**, then select **Next**.
> 4. On the Verify your identity screen, choose to receive your security
>      code either as a text or email message. If you choose text, type the
>      last four digits of your phone number, and then select **Send code**.
>      Learn more about security info and security codes.
> 5. When you get the code as a text or email message on a separate
>      device, enter it and then select Next.
> 6. On the Reset your password screen, create a new password, and then
>      select **Next**. This sets your new password. Select **Next** again to
>      return to the sign-in screen.
> 7. Sign in with your new Microsoft account password.
>
> [Get more help signing in to your Microsoft
>   account](https://support.microsoft.com/help/12429)